# Id of a selectedlist from partialview is not passed to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view with three dropdowns, which is displayed in a few view of my webpage.

[image]

I need to send the selected id of the last dropdown to controller:
This is the last dropdown in the partial view:

```
 <div class="col-sm-10">
   @Html.DropDownList("engines", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select engine--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
 </div>
```

I tried a lot of possibilities, but none of them worked. Not even the alert is not working when the engine dropdown changes.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#engines").change(function () {
        document.getElementById("btnSearch").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("result").hidden = false;


        alert($('#engines').val());
    })
```

I've tried this way, but the method of my controller is not invoked:

```
var UrlSettings = {
    ModelsUrl: '@Url.Action("GetModels", "Home")',
    EngineUrl: '@Url.Action("GetEngines", "Home")',
    EngineChange: '@Url.Action("ChangeEngine", "Home")'
}

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#engines").change(function () {
        document.getElementById("btnSearch").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("result").hidden = false;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: UrlSettings.EngineChange,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#engines").val() },
            success: function (engines) {                    
            },
            error: function (ex) {                   
            }
        });
    })`enter code here`
});
```

This is the method from controller where I need to pass the id as parameter

```
public JsonResult ChangeEngine(int? id)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
```

This is my full partial view Html code:

```
<div class="car-filter-wrapper">
@*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchForCars", "Home", null))//, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DivCategoriesTree", OnSuccess = "success", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { make = "makes" }))
    {*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchForCars", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 10em;display: flex;align-items: center ; padding-top:25px;">
        <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red; padding-left:20px;"></i>
        <strong style="padding-left:20px;"></strong>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div style="padding-top:15px;">
            <form class="form-control-static">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("makes"))
                        {
                        @Html.DropDownList("makes", ViewData["makes"] as List<SelectListItem>, "--Select--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <p></p>
                            @Html.DropDownList("models", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p></p>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            @Html.DropDownList("engines", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 10em;display: flex;align-items: center ; padding-top:25px;">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SearchForCars", "Home")'" class="btn btn-default active" value="Search" disabled="disabled" style="width:150px;" />
    </div>
}
```

Could you please help on this problem?

Comment: put in the partial view code HTML

Comment: Is it making an AJAX call but returning 404? or is it not making the AJAX call at all? Did you notice any error in the console of developer tools?

Comment: @Prashanth Benny - I've updated the question with the html code

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya - it's not making the Ajax call at all. I didn't notice any error

Comment: Actually when I use the onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SearchForCars", "Home")'",(it would be ok to reach this method too), I get : Server Error in '/' Application.The resource cannot be found. Altought I have this method in the Home controller  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchForCars(int makes, int models, int engines){....}

Comment: The dropdown has only one value? Can you share what exact values you are populating in the dropdown list?

Comment: It depends what is selected from the second dropdown. It contains a list of engines of the previously selected car model and car make.

Comment: I would suggest to put some hard coded values in the dropdown list and also set the ajax `url` hard codes instead of using @Url.Action . It look like the MVC syntax and JS syntax messing with each other. I am sure you know how to see the JS errors in the Console of developer tools.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented the same solution as you as following and It worked fine for me.

Dropdown below contains some hard coded items of class `AudioClass`.

```
@Html.DropDownList("engines", new SelectList(new List<AudioClass> {new AudioClass {Id=1, Name = "Audio1"}, new AudioClass { Id = 2, Name = "Audio2" } }, "Id", "Name"), "--Select engine--", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle form-control" })
```

My script block look as following.

```
<script>
var UrlSettings = {
    EngineChange: '@Url.Action("Process", "Home")',
}
$(document)
    .ready(function() {
        $("#engines")
            .change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: UrlSettings.EngineChange,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#engines").val() },
                    success: function (engines) {                         
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

A couple of tips.
Returning `Json(null)` from controller action would return to error block of ajax so make sure you return valid JSON from the server so that you don't get false positives.

I have not included lines of `document.getElementById` as they were not relevant to me. But if you are including it in your code then make sure that those elements exist in the DOM or you put a null check before you deal with them otherwise the code will error out on those lines and AJAX call will not happen.

```
if (document.getElementById("btnSearch") != null) {
    document.getElementById("btnSearch").disabled = false;
}

if (document.getElementById("result") != null) {
    document.getElementById("result").hidden = false;
}
```

The error you would see will be `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null` in the console of developer tool.

I hope this would help you to identify the possible problems in your code and solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! I spent hours to resolve this and I didn't realize that actually I don't have anymore the document.getElementById("result") on my partial view.